# How do you use setuptools to build a Python package containing runtime libraries?

Tags: python, swig, setuptools

**Background:**

I've used SWIG to develop a Python wrapper for a C/C++ library.

Now I need to use `setuptools` to package the project for distribution. The package needs to include the SWIG generated C extension and all DLL dependencies. My project directory looks like the following:

```
project_directory/
  |
  --- foo_mod/
  |      |
  |      --- __init__.py
  |
  --- libs/
  |    |
  |    --- lib_a.dll
  |    --- lib_b.dll
  |
  --- core.py (generated by SWIG)
  --- core_wrap.cxx (generated by SWIG)
  --- core_wrap.h
  --- setup.py
```

**What I have tried:**

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages, Extension

application_module = Extension(
    '_core',
)

setup(
    name='foo_mod',
    version='0.1',
    author="My Name",
    email="my.name@company.com",
    description="""Simple example""",
    ext_modules=[application_module],
    packages=find_packages(),
    package_data={
        "" : ['libs/*.dll']
    },
    py_modules=['core'],
    python_requires='>=3.6')
```

**Command to build the extension:**

```
PS > python setup.py build_ext --build-lib .\foo_mod
```

Following this command, the python extension `_core.pyd` is written to `foo_mod\`.

**Command to build the package:**

```
PS > python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel
```

**Problem:**
The `_core.pyd` extension and libs are not being included into the wheel.

**Question:**
How do I properly include the library dependencies into the package?

Comment: 1. AFAIK `package_data` can't include files for an empty string, it should be a package name that is included in the distribution (=contained in the `packages` list). 2. The `_core.pyd` is probably not included because you have named the extension `_core`, but are placing the lib into `foo_mod` - in that case, the extension name should be `foo_mod._core`. I may be wrong though - complete the question to a [mcve] to be reproducible locally.

Comment: @hoefling 1) From the [documentation](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#including-data-files), the empty string is used to apply the associated rule to all packages found by `find_packages`. 2) It appears I was mistaken. The .pyd is being detected and included by `setuptools`. The DLLs are the only ones I can't seem to get it to find and include.

Comment: Yes, I see. I guess the error is then that your `libs` directory doesn't belong to any package, move it inside the `foo_mod` directory to fix.